# How to enter complex (nested) variables in Terraform Cloud?

Tags: terraform

In Terraform Cloud, we have a web user inteface like this to assign values to variables:

[image]

How do I enter a variable like this in above UI so I can properly see the hirearchy the way I see in .tfavr files?

```
tef_var = {
  nested = {
    key1 = value1
    key2 = value3
    key3 = value4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/variables.html#hcl-values

> To enter list or map values, click the variable's "HCL" checkbox (visible when editing) and enter the value with the same HCL syntax you would use when writing Terraform code. For example:

```
{
    us-east-1 = "image-1234"
    us-west-2 = "image-4567"
}
```

This worked for me.

```
nested = {
  key1 = "value1"
  key2 = "value3"
  key3 = "value4"
}
```

[image: terraform cloud hcl map variable]